# Does anyone know how to insert a year value into a date so the day and month stay the same

Tags: sql, database, date, datetime, ms-access

Hi I'm trying to create a date due system

The SQL I have been using is:

```
SELECT client,make, model,units, expires AS [last checked], dateadd("d",168'[expires]) AS [dates due]
FROM [ServicingDetails]
WHERE expires >= #1/1/2020# and expires >=#28/1/2020#
```

How would I get the 2020 to update to 2021 every year?

Comment: And what do you do with Feb 29th?

Comment: Please make up your mind. 1: _how to insert a year value into a date so the day and month stay the same_,  2: _display the work in 4 week periods_,  3: _update only the year to the current year_.

Comment: `expires >= #1/1/2020# and expires >=#28/1/2020#` is equivalent to `expires >=#28/1/2020#` or you want something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `DateSerial` to construct a date, and `Year(Date())` to get the current year, e.g.

```
WHERE expires >= DateSerial(Year(Date()), 1,1) and expires >= DateSerial(Year(Date()), 1, 28)
```